# Encoding to something occurs only from certain encoding?

Tags: python, pandas

I have files in pandas that I want to turn to a certain encoding but I have to change it first to another in order to happen because it can't from their first encoding. Why is this happening and how to make it in a piece of code that has hundreds of lines?

How to change it massively to the encoding which then can change to the desired one?
say I have the files in this:`iso8859_6`
I want to turn it to:`iso8859_14`
but to make this happen I have to turn it first to :`iso8859_16`

How can  I do this without first running all the code in the 3d encoding and then the wanted encoding?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem and demonstrate your attempt at solving it.

Comment: Actually i describe how i solved it, i first turn it to a different encoding and then to the final. The question is if there is another way to do it.Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at the linked webpage? It would be good to see the code. From the description it is very hard to say what you did and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That sounds odd. Normally you decode the input bytes to Unicode text and then encode the text to the desired output encoding bytes.

Comment: yes i know it looks like it needs to do the change from certain encoding that's why it needs to do it to a certain first before it allows you to do it to what you want.